# Faster Query Execution

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 42 columns and 4 joins in my table. Execution needs 140 seconds, I want to reduce the time of execution. What to do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT GR_ID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR, GR_DT, 106) AS GRDate,
                GR_GN,
                GR_GID,
                GR_BS,
                GR_BN,
                GR_DC,
                GR_COP,
                GR_PA,
                GR_AR,
                GR_BG,
                GR_SM,
                GR_KG,
                GR_IN,
                GR_TS,
                CMLC_BC,
                CMLC_SC,
                CMLC_KG,
                CMLC_BL,
                CMBC_BC,
                CMBC_SC,
                CMBC_KG,
                CMBC_BL,
                GR_BRN,
                GR_BLC,
                GR_LEA,
                GR_ALF,
                GR_BTA,
                GR_PID,
                GR_UTS,
                GR_LR,
                CMGB_BC,
                CMGB_SC,
                CMGB_KG,
                CMGB_BL,
                CMGB_LR,
                GR_UPC,
                GR_UPT,
                GR_UTA,
                GR_TTA,
                GR_SPA,
                GR_SAR,
                GR_NR,
                ISNULL(ACK_ACK, 'NO')        AS ACK_ACK
FROM   GR
       LEFT JOIN CMBC
         ON ( CMBC_ID = GR_GID )
            AND ( CMBC_IID = GR_PID )
       RIGHT JOIN CMLC
         ON ( CMLC_ID = GR_GID )
            AND ( CMLC_IID = GR_PID )
       RIGHT JOIN CMGB
         ON ( CMGB_ID = GR_GID )
            AND ( CMGB_IID = GR_PID )
            AND ( CMGB_TS = GR_UTS )
       LEFT JOIN ACK
         ON ( ACK_GN = GR_GN )
            AND ( ACK_GID = GR_GID )
ORDER  BY GR_GN,
          GR_GID
```

Comment: please post execution plan and schema of tables involved.Also look how to ask to get help faster:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, please think about the poor guy that will have to look at your code 18 months from now and figure out what the hell are `GR_AR`, `GR_TS` or `GR_ALF`. Use meaningful names, you'll thank me later.

Comment: @TheGameiswar why are you making syntax edits?

Comment: This was already edited ,i have clicked improved edit ,so that the person who edited will get credit and also changed little formatting to show in multiple lines

Comment: @TheGameiswar It looks like you've corrected or changed something in the actual query. Removing/adding a couple things. You shouldn't be fixing code in edits.

Comment: @Mohit, your Distinct is one of the reason to make your execution slow, you could have used group by instead

Comment: @Prathyush - this won't make any difference.

Comment: @MartinSmith, if OP keep Distinct then he has to create index on each select column(s) which is not easy in this case.

Comment: @Prathyush - whether the duplicates are removed by `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` makes no difference to the work required or execution plan.

Comment: Why the constraint on 140 seconds? If this forms part of a scheduled job have you thought about caching the results of this heavy query into a table then just reading from the table where you need the performance?

Comment: can i use index to column(Use for Join) for improve performance?